# SQL Syntax Error: Remove/Disclude Apostrophe's?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, syntax-error

I use the below code to update a Business' information on one of my Windows Forms. When a user puts the Business name in txtBusName as something like "**Sandy's Place**" I receive `Incorrect Syntax near ';'. Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ';'.`

What is the best way to handle this issue?

```
conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

mskZip.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals;
string zip = mskZip.Text;
mskZip.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.IncludeLiterals;
mskMailZip.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals;
string mailzip = mskMailZip.Text;
mskMailZip.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.IncludeLiterals;
mskPhone.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals;
string phone = mskPhone.Text;
mskPhone.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.IncludeLiterals;
mskFax.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals;
string fax = mskFax.Text;
mskFax.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.IncludeLiterals;


cmd.CommandText = "Update Business SET Name='" + txtBusName.Text + "', ContactName='" + txtContName.Text +
                "', Address='" + txtAddr1.Text + "', City='" + txtCity.Text + "', State='" + cmbState.Text + "', Zip=" + ((zip=="")?"NULL":zip) + ", " +
                "MailAddress='" + txtMailAddr1.Text + "', MailCity='" + txtMailCity.Text + "', MailState='" + cmbMailState.Text +
                "', MailZipcode=" + ((mailzip == "") ? "NULL" : mailzip) + ", Latitude=" + ((txtLat.Text == "") ? "NULL" : txtLat.Text) + ", Longitude=" + ((txtLong.Text == "") ? "NULL" : txtLong.Text) + ", Phone=" +
                ((phone == "") ? "NULL" : phone) + ", Fax=" + ((fax == "") ? "NULL" : fax) + ", Email='" + txtEmail.Text + "' " +
                "WHERE BusinessID=" + busID + " AND Status='A';";

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

MessageBox.Show("Database updated successfully.");
this.Close();
```

Comment: Use parameterized query

Comment: @Steve how does parameterized query assist with preventing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [parameterized query](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) like this

```
cmd.CommandText = 
        "Update Business SET Name=@name, ContactName=@contact, Address=@address, " + 
                "City=@city, State=@state, Zip=@zip, " +
                "MailAddress=@mail, MailCity=@ecity, MailState=@estate, " +
                "MailZipcode=@ezip, Latitude=@lat, Longitude=@lng, Phone=@phone, " +
                "Fax=@fax, Email=@email " +
                "WHERE BusinessID=@busID AND Status='A'";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtBusName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact", txtContName.Text); 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtAddr1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", txtCity.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", cmbState.Text);

SqlParameter p1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@zip", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
if(zip == "") p1.Value = DBNull.Value; else p1.Value = zip;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mail",  txtMailAddr1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ecity", txtMailCity.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estate", cmbMailState.Text);

p1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ezip", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
if (mailzip == "") p1.Value = DBNull.Value; else p1.Value = mailzip;

p1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@lat", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
if (txtLat.Text == "") p1.Value = DBNull.Value; else p1.Value = txtLat.Text;

p1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@lng", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
if (txtLong.Text == "") p1.Value = DBNull.Value; else p1.Value = txtLong.Text;

p1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@phone", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
if (phone == "") p1.Value = DBNull.Value; else p1.Value = phone;

p1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@fax", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
if (fax == "") p1.Value = DBNull.Value; else p1.Value = fax;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmail.Text );
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@busID", busID);
```

The article linked above is worth to read from start to end, however, to summarize, using a parameterized query you let the work to format  the single quotes (and also numeric decimals and date literals) to the framework code that knows better than me and you how to deal with that strings and also in this way you avoid the dreaded [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) problem that could expose your database to hacking

NOTE: I don't know the actual datatype for the columns that should be set to null, so I have assumed that they are all NVARCHAR. If this is not the case then you should replace the SqlDbType with the appropriate value.

Comment: Thanks for the clear example! I can see the security issues with the previous code now :S I am having one problem: When I hover over any of the `DBNull.Value : ...` I have a red mark that says: "**Error: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.DBNull' and 'string'**".

Comment: Yes, I see the problem, fixing now

Comment: Looks like **Zip** is Varchar(15), **MailZipCode** Varchar(15), **Latitude** Varchar(20), **Longitude** Varchar(20), **Phone** Varchar(25), **Fax** Varchar(25). Will change code over and let you know.

Answer (score 2):

Escape single quotes in SQL by using double single quotes, so `Sandy''s place` should work.

I would strongly advice on using query parameters instead of stringing together your own query, this fixes a potential security risk (SQL injection) and most probably problems like your quotes as well.

Comment: I see what you mean about the Injection risk. How would a parameterized query help with this matter though?

Comment: Because it will take care about encoding special characters etc.

Answer (score 1):

Please use SqlParameter object and not a string concatenation like that. Something like:

```
    string sql = "Update Business SET Name=@Name, ContactName=@ContactName, Address=@Address WHERE BusinessID=@BusinessID AND Status='A';";
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[] par = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[4];
    par[0] = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Name", txtBusName.Text);
    par[1] = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ContactName", txtContName.Text);
    par[2] = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Address", txtAddr1.Text);
    par[3] = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@BusinessID", busID);

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand com = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, SQL_CONNECTION);
        com.Parameters.AddRange(par);
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Too many parameters you had so didn't write them all :)

Using this approach will take care of special characters like the apostrophe for you plus make code look cleaner, more readable and more secure.

Comment: Thanks for typing out what you did :) How does that assist with the issue of the extra quotation mark though?

Comment: If you use SqlParameter it will take care of special characters for you like the apostrophe or certain symbols (can't remember off the top of my head).

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use a parameterised query.

eg: http://www.aspsnippets.com/articles/Using-Parameterized-queries-to-prevent-SQL-Injection-Attacks-in-SQL-Server.aspx